# Dygraphs : stackedgraph is used per-series?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I want to display an stacked graph and a line graph to one graph, but feel it so that stackedgraph is not usable in per-series.
How can I use this ?

```
g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graph"),
             "X,Y1,Y2,Y3\n" +
             "0,25,0,30\n" +
             "1,20,10,27\n" +
             "2,17,17,30\n" +
             "3,16,23,28\n" +
             "4,14,27,30\n" +
             "5,13,30,29\n" +
             "6,12,32,30\n" +
             "7,11,33,30\n",
             {
                "Y1": {
                     stackedGraph: true, fillGraph: true
                 },
                "Y2": {
                    stackedGraph: true, fillGraph: true
                },
                "Y3": {
                    stackedGraph: false, fillGraph: false, strokeWidth: 2
                }, 
                 title: 'Test'
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `stackedGraph` option cannot be set on a per-series or per-axis basis.

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues/324) to make this and other options per-axis, but there are no immediate plans to support this.

Comment: I decided that I coordinated a program by oneself and used it. 
I await official update